# SSIS Script Component C#: Can we use System.Reflection to find the buffer length of an Input Column?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl

Normally, inside an SSIS component, the input column of type "String" has a user defined length.

Example in my Output0Buffer, I have Column1 DataType=Unicode string [DT_WSTR] Length=15.

Inside the SSIS program (C#), would it be possible to find the value "15" programmatically? I normally use System.Reflection to get the data type and use SetValue method to assign values in my buffer.

Example:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo p in props)
        {
            if (p.GetType() == typeof(string))
            {
                p.SetValue(Output0Buffer, Convert.ToString(value), null);
            }
            ...
        }
```

But sometimes, I exceed the buffer size and this throws an exception. Rather than have this, I was hoping I would be able to get the buffer length so I could truncate the values before I assign them to the buffer.

---

Alternatively, I could always do the traditional way of assigning values of the buffer
i.e. Output0Buffer.Column1 = value.substring(0,15);

but that would be too much code typing :) I'd rather try to loop through by Buffer properties and populate accordingly.

Hope you guys can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this is what you were looking for:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer InputBufferRow)
{
     //For InputBuffer
    foreach (IDTSInputColumn100 iColumn in this.ComponentMetaData.InputCollection[0].InputColumnCollection)
    {
        string iName = iColumn.Name;
        string iType = iColumn.DataType.ToString();
        string iLength = iColumn.Length.ToString();
        string iPrecision = iColumn.Precision.ToString();
    }

    //For OutputBuffer
    foreach (IDTSOutputColumn100 oColumn in this.ComponentMetaData.OutputCollection[0].OutputColumnCollection)
    {
        string oName = oColumn.Name;
        string oType = oColumn.DataType.ToString();
        string oLength = oColumn.Length.ToString();
        string oPrecision = oColumn.Precision.ToString();
    }
 }
```

These interfaces are available in the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper` namespace. They have other properties that you may be interested in as well for what you are trying to do other than what is listed here.